# Google Spreadsheets APIS, confused

Tags: swift, xcode, google-sheets-api

I had this working before but now it seems to have stopped. I am trying to run various googlesheets APIS such as read/write/create. I have installed the appropriate cocoa pods:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'Safety_App-Prototype' do
  
  use_frameworks!

    pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
    pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Sheets'
    pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Drive'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
end
```

I have created a google developer console project and included all relevant information into my app. (this includes the URL type under projects -> info tab as well as in my app delegate shown below:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  Created by Michael Szabo on 2021-01-28.
//

import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "FORMYEYESONLY.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
   
        
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL?,
                                                 sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                 annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

    
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
          if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.hasNoAuthInKeychain.rawValue {
            print("The user has not signed in before or they have since signed out.")
          } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
          }
          return
        }
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
        let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
        let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
        let fullName = user.profile.name
        let givenName = user.profile.givenName
        let familyName = user.profile.familyName
        let email = user.profile.email
        // ...
        print(fullName)
    }
    
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
       // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
        print("User has disconnected")
    }
    
    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

I have added a google signing button which allows me to sign in and asks for permission to read/write to sheets and added functions in my script to create/read/write to sheets as seen below:

```
//  Created by Michael Szabo on 2021-02-21.
//


import GoogleAPIClientForREST
import GoogleSignIn
import UIKit

class JHA_pg1: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {
    

    var rowstart:NSNumber = 0
    var rowend:NSNumber = 0
    var columnstart:NSNumber = 0
    var columnend:NSNumber = 0
    var red:NSNumber = 1
    var blue:NSNumber = 1
    var green:NSNumber = 1

    var range1 = ""
    var text1 = ""
    var text2 = ""
    var text3 = ""
    var bordertype = "SOLID"
    var borderthick:NSNumber = 3
    var inbortype = "NONE"
    var inborthick:NSNumber = 0
        
    var spreadsheetId = ""
    
   
    @IBOutlet weak var BeginAssessment: UIButton! //SubmitButton
 
    let today = Date()
    let formatter1 = DateFormatter()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    var date = String()
    var buttontitle = String()
        
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        
        
    private let scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsSpreadsheets]
    private let service = GTLRSheetsService()
   

    
//=========================================================================================================
//=========================================================================================================

    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        
        
//=========================================================================================================
// Configure Google Sign-in.

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = scopes
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()

        
    }
    
    
//=========================================================================================================
//=========================================================================================================
    //Submit Function

    @IBAction func BeginAssessment(_ sender: Any) {
   
        
        if(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser != nil)
        {
        print("loggedIn")
        }
        else
        {
        print("not loggedIn")
        }
        

        
        spreadsheetId = "SOME ID"
        rowstart = 0
        rowend = 5
        columnstart = 0
        columnend = 7
  
        unmergecell()
        
  

        CreateSpreadSheet()
        
        print(spreadsheetId)
        
     
 
    }
        

    //========================================================================================================
    //Write To Sheet Function
        
        func write() {
            let range = range1
            let updateValues = [[text1,text2,text3]]
            let valueRange = GTLRSheets_ValueRange() // GTLRSheets_ValueRange holds the updated values and other params
            valueRange.majorDimension = "ROWS" // Indicates horizontal row insert
            valueRange.range = range
            valueRange.values = updateValues
            let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesAppend.query(withObject: valueRange, spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId, range: range)
            query.valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED"
            
            service.executeQuery(query) { ticket, object, error in}
        }
      
   
    //========================================================================================================
    //Unmerge Cell Function

            func unmergecell() {
                
                let request = GTLRSheets_Request.init()

                let test = GTLRSheets_GridRange.init()
                    
                test.startRowIndex = rowstart
                test.endRowIndex = rowend
                test.startColumnIndex = columnstart
                test.endColumnIndex = columnend

                request.unmergeCells = GTLRSheets_UnmergeCellsRequest.init()
                request.unmergeCells?.range = test

                

                let batchUpdate = GTLRSheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.init()
                
                batchUpdate.requests = [request]
               
            
                let createQuery = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsBatchUpdate.query(withObject: batchUpdate, spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId)
              
                
            service.executeQuery(createQuery) { (ticket, result, NSError) in
                   
                   }
                  }
        

                       }
        
    //========================================================================================================
    //Create Spreadsheet Function

        
        func CreateSpreadSheet()
        {
            
            print("==============================================")
            print("Createsheet Function")
            
            let newSheet = GTLRSheets_Spreadsheet.init()
            let properties = GTLRSheets_SpreadsheetProperties.init()

            properties.title = "Daily JHA Form - "+date
            newSheet.properties = properties
            
            let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsCreate.query(withObject:newSheet)
            query.fields = "spreadsheetId"

            query.completionBlock = { (ticket, result, NSError) in

                if let error = NSError {
                    print("error!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
                    print(error)
                }
                else {
                    let response = result as! GTLRSheets_Spreadsheet
                    let identifier = response.spreadsheetId
                    self.spreadsheetId = identifier!
                    GlobalVariable1.sheetID = self.spreadsheetId
                    print(self.spreadsheetId)
                }
            }
            service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: nil)
        
        }


 
  //=========================================================================================================
    
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
          if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.hasNoAuthInKeychain.rawValue {
            print("The user has not signed in before or they have since signed out.")
          } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
          }
          return
        }
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
        let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
        let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
        let fullName = user.profile.name
        let givenName = user.profile.givenName
        let familyName = user.profile.familyName
        let email = user.profile.email
        // ...
        print(fullName)
    }
    
    
    //=========================================================================================================
    // Display (in the UITextView) the names and majors of students in a sample
    // spreadsheet:
    //https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTxKKu-0BwyOPq9HTYH237jGlMrf3q8kLwe5R2eH2dbkGqNbk3D7L9_MKxpO4b3g9cy09w2davohJzq/pubhtml
            
            func listMajors() {

        let range = "A1:Q"
        let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesGet
                    .query(withSpreadsheetId: spreadsheetId, range:range)
                service.executeQuery(query) { (ticket, result, error) in
        if let error = error {
        self.showAlert(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
        return
                    }
        guard let result = result as? GTLRSheets_ValueRange else {
        return
                    }
        let rows = result.values!
        if rows.isEmpty {
    //    self.output.text = "No data found."
        return
                    }
    //    self.output.text = "Number of rows in sheet: \(rows.count)"
                }
            }
            

    // Process the response and display output
        func displayResultWithTicket(ticket: GTLRServiceTicket,
    finishedWithObject result : GTLRSheets_ValueRange,
    error : NSError?) {
    if let error = error {
    showAlert(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
    return
            }
    var majorsString = ""
    let rows = result.values!
    if rows.isEmpty {
    //           output.text = "No data found."
    return
            }
            majorsString += "Name, Major:\n"
    for row in rows {
    let name = row[0]
    let major = row[4]
                majorsString += "\(name), \(major)\n"
            }
    //        output.text = majorsString
        }
        
        
        
    // Helper for showing an alert
        func showAlert(title : String, message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(
    title: title,
    message: message,
    preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert
            )
    let ok = UIAlertAction(
    title: "OK",
    style: UIAlertAction.Style.default,
    handler: nil
            )
            alert.addAction(ok)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


}


struct GlobalVariable1
{
    static var sheetID = ""
}


extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

}
```

HOWEVER I get the following error:

> Optional(Error Domain=com.google.GTLRErrorObjectDomain Code=401 "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22) UserInfo={GTLRStructuredError=GTLRErrorObject 0x600001182310: {errors:[1] message:"Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22) code:401 status:"UNAUTHENTICATED"}, NSLocalizedDescription=Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.}](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%7D))"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I’m having a similar issue. Anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I was missing an instruction in my functions being called. I also had to update a bit of my code for newer pod file "pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 5.0.2'" The instructions for this migration can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide

The portion of code I needed to add to my functions is a simple line which can be seen here:

service.authorizer = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()

I hope this helps someone else out (pass it on.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Looking to the error generated by your code, and the scopes you try to require, it seems they are not enough. Indeed you set only:

```
private let scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsSpreadsheets]
```

According to this [google official doc about scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes) you can find more details about all the scopes.
In the middle part of your code you read profile informations and these info could be readed adding scopes about [google sign in](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#google-sign-in):

- profile
- email

Comment: Hi Alessandro, Thank you for the input. It definitely helped push me in the right direction. I was able to find what I was missing. Please see bellow: